# java web start deployment property file reading

Tags: java, file, properties, java-web-start

I am trying to deploy a very simple application in Java Web Start. I am totally new to this.

My application contains one Java file. On running the application by java (java CustomDemo) it displays a dialog which contains a button. When user clicks that button a property file will be read and Hello World will be displayed on the dialog as a Label.

- N.B : Inside one folder I have the java class as well as .properties 
  file.

I want to deploy that application in Web Start.

Steps I followed.

1. I have made a jar of my application (jar -cvf SampleDemo.jar CustomDialog.class).
2. I have written the jnlp file.
3. I created a index.html page
4. Kept the whole thing in tomcat/webapps and deploying in tomcat.

Now the problem is that If I display the label as any hardcoded String then the application is working like a charm. But as soon as I am reading the properties file I am getting exception  while running in Java Web Start that "File Not Found Eception"

My sample codes are as follows

### CustomDialog.java

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTable;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Properties;

public class CustomDialog extends JDialog implements ActionListener
{
    protected boolean i_boolButtonClicked = false;
    protected String LABEL                = "";

    public CustomDialog()
    {
        this.setSize(500, 300);
        JButton but = new JButton("Hello");


        //Start Anjan to read data/text from .properties file..
        Properties  i_propConfig        = new Properties();
        try
        {
            FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream("./Test.properties");
            i_propConfig.load( inStream  );
            inStream.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String l_strKey = "";
        String l_strVal = "";

        Enumeration l_enum = i_propConfig.keys();
        while(l_enum.hasMoreElements())
        {
            l_strKey = (String)l_enum.nextElement();

            if(l_strKey == null || l_strKey.equals( "" ))
                continue;

            l_strVal = i_propConfig.getProperty( l_strKey );

            if(l_strVal == null || l_strVal.equals( "" ))
                continue;
        }

        System.out.println("Properties read from file--> Key: "+l_strKey +" Value: " +l_strVal);
        LABEL = l_strVal;
        //End Anjan to read data/text from .properties file..

//      but.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
//      {
//          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
//          {
//              //getContentPane().add(new JLabel("Hello World"));
//              getContentPane().add(new JLabel(LABEL));
//              getContentPane().validate();
//          }
//      });

        but.addActionListener(this);

        Dimension dim=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();          
        this.setLocation((int)(dim.width- getWidth ())/2,(int)(dim.height-this.getHeight ())/2);

        but.setSize(600, 5);
        this.add(but);
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        CustomDialog l_objCustomDialog = new CustomDialog();
    }

    protected void processWindowEvent(WindowEvent e) 
    {
        super.processWindowEvent(e);

        if (e.getID() == WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING) 
        {
            setVisible(false);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        System.out.println("Hello button clicked......");
        getContentPane().add(new JLabel(LABEL));
        getContentPane().validate();
    }
}
```

### SwingDemo.jnlp

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://172.28.1.139:8400/SwingDemo" href="SwingDemo.jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>Swing Demo</title>
        <vendor>Swing</vendor>
    </information>
    <resources>
        <!-- Application Resources -->
        <j2se version="1.6+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
        <jar href="SwingDemo.jar" main="true" download="eager" />
    </resources>

    <application-desc
         name="SwingDemo Demo Application"
         main-class="SwingDemo.CustomDialog"
         width="300"
         height="300">
     </application-desc>
     <update check="background"/>

<security>
    <all-permissions/>
</security>
</jnlp>
```

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
 <HEAD>
  <TITLE> New Document </TITLE>
  <META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="EditPlus">
  <META NAME="Author" CONTENT="">
  <META NAME="Keywords" CONTENT="">
  <META NAME="Description" CONTENT="">
 </HEAD>

 <BODY>
    <script src="http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
    <script>
        // using JavaScript to get location of JNLP file relative to HTML page
        var dir = location.href.substring(0,location.href.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        var url = dir + "SwingDemo.jnlp";
        deployJava.createWebStartLaunchButton(url, '1.6.0');
    </script>
 </BODY>
</HTML>
```

For a few days I am just digging and could not find any solution out.I think there must be some other way of reading .properties file in web start. Can anyone suggest any clear and smart way outso that the problem can be solved.

And one more thing I dont want to pin the properties file inside my jar. Even I tried that way also.

Answer (score 2):

The way to fix a `FileNotFoundException` in a JWS app. is to access the resource by URL.

That URL can be formed using `getClass.getResource(String)` if the properties file is on the run-time class-path of the JWS app. (in a Jar referenced in a `jar` element in the JNLP).

If the resource is loose on the server, an URL can be formed relative to the code base or document base (if it is an applet).

Note that URLs mean effectively 'read only' as opposed to 'read/write'.  In the case the properties change, we need to pursue a more complex strategy to serialize them locally.

Answer (score 0):

@Andrew Thompson 
     I have followed the way of loading the resource as you mentioned. The snippet of code is here :

```
String url = "Test.properties";

System.out.println("Before printing paths..");
System.out.println("Path2: "+ getClass().getResource(url).getPath());

FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(getClass().getResource(url).toURI()));
i_propConfig.load(inputStream);
inputStream.close();
```

I have configured it in eclipse with the hierarchy (Under source there is a folder called SwingDemo. In SwingDemo there is my java file as well as the resource file)...

*src

```
  *SwingDemo

      *CustomDialog.java

      *Test.properties
```

When I am running this on eclipse everything is running fine. But as soon as I attempt to run the apps from cmd line null pointer exception is occuring..

Command Line deployment hierarchy is as follows:

Folder : D:\Work\Java Progrms\SwingDemo

Hierarchy: *SwingDemo

```
              *CustomDialog.java            

              *Test.properties
```

First of all I compiled this file inside SwingDemo folder from cmd line (javac CustomDialog.java). Then I move one step back to Java Progrms folder (as I mentioned the  package inside .java class) and run the apps by using the famous "java SwingDemo.CustomDialog". I used to follow similar steps when I used new FileInputStream("path") previously. 
      After doing this fashion I am getting null pointer exception..

I think "getClass().getResource(url)" cannot load file from a specific directory. Thats why I put the resource in same diredtory as that of my java file. It ran fine in Eclipse. But why this is giving error when I run from Command Line.

Comment: *"as soon as I attempt to run the apps from cmd line null pointer exception is occuring.."*  This is not an answer.  It should be edited into the question.